# C# How to use a while loop with a percentage from a TextBox

Tags: c#

I have been searching of a way to do this little exercise from my programming book, but I'm not able to think how to do this.

Here is what I have so far:

```
private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int numOrg = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumOrg.Text); 
    double numberToConvert = Convert.ToDouble(txtDailyIncrease.Text); // percent

    double convertToDecimal = (numberToConvert / 100);

    while (numOrg <= 10)
    {
        lstDisplay.Items.Add(numOrg + "   " + convertToDecimal  );  
        numOrg++;
    }
}
```

For the values I am using: `numOrg` is 2 and numberToConvert is 30%.

The expected output should be: 2.6000, 3.3800, 4.3940, etc.

I just want to add an increase to my number each day. I definitely over complicated this simple task, but I've put 7 hours into this already and I'm not getting anywhere so I'm hoping someone can help me see this problem a little more clearly. Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Do you want to calculate percentage ? Please clarify your problem clearly..

Comment: I want to add 30% increase to my number each day. For example, the first day is 2 so, 2.6... the next day is 3 so the old value (2.6 + 30%)

Comment: At the moment you're only dividing the entered percentage by 100 and adding it to `lstDisplay` multiple times. You need to do some calculation with that value (I assume you have some basic knowledge of maths...)

Comment: Suppose you enter 100 in `numOrg` and 10 in `DailyIncrease`. Are you expecting increament of `numOrg` by 10 % should add in `lstDisplay`? So in `lstDisplay`110 should be added. Is this your requirement?

Comment: Yes, exactly, and then the next number would be 101 with the 10% DailyIncrease so on and so forth

Comment: Up to which number you want to add into 'lstDisplay' ?

Comment: just up to 10 max

Answer (score 2):

Please check this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var numOrg = 2;
        var percentage = 0.3;
        var result = (double)numOrg;
        while (numOrg <= 10)
        {
            result += percentage * result;
            Console.WriteLine($"{numOrg}: {result}");
            numOrg++;
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

It generates expected result:

```
2: 2,6
3: 3,38
4: 4,394
5: 5,7122
6: 7,42586
7: 9,653618
8: 12,5497034
9: 16,31461442
10: 21,208998746
```

I dont't know what exact logic is behind your code. Maybe you should loop from 1 to stop value and use numOrg only as value for calculations.

Comment: Hi there, sorry for the code example I provided. This was after my second day of trying to get the result. Your example made this so clear for me to understand. Now I feel silly that I wasn't able to figure this out lol. Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int numOrg = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumOrg.Text);
            double numberToConvert = double.Parse(txtDailyIncrease.Text); // percent

            double convertToDecimal = (numberToConvert / 100);

            var result = double.Parse(txtNumOrg.Text);

            while (numOrg <= 10)
            {
                result += convertToDecimal * result;
                lstDisplay.Items.Add(result);

                numOrg++;
            }



        }
```

[image]